# Create-react-app produces command not found

Tags: reactjs, macos, terminal

I've just started the ravenous react proj, and I can't install my new react app ("create-react-app ravenous") in the terminal.

It tells me the the command is not found ("-bash: create-react-app: command not found").

link to the task:

(https://www.codecademy.com/paths/web-development/tracks/front-end-applications-with-react/modules/ravenous-part-one/projects/create-prj-components)

I checked again to verify that the npm is installed globally (which it was).

I checked also npm -v and it showed me "6.9.0".
and I checked  that I'm doing all of that process in an empty new folder I've created especially for this particular project.
I use mac and I've tried both "sudo-create-react app" & "create -react-app".

ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$ pwd
/Users/ITAI2700/Desktop/codecademy-final-proj

ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$ ls
node_modules

ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$ npm -v
6.9.0

ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$ create-react-app -v
-bash: create-react-app: command not found

ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$ sudo create-react-app ravenous

sudo: create-react-app: command not found
ITAIs-MacBook-Pro:codecademy-final-proj ITAI2700$

install raect in my codecademy-final-proj folder

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have not installed it **globally**. Try installing with the -g flag.

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

then to create an application in your desired directory

eg : I am now in **/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/**

```
$/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ create-react-app helloreact
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred methods for installing a create-react-app are now:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

or

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

Your npm version is up-to-date enough to use the 1st option, have a try at that and see if it works

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

Install npx package with os package manager and create-react-app from npm.
and then use 
`npx create-react-app my-app`